# Cannot connect to Hyper-V Ubuntu VM after update to 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, hyper-v

Over the weekend I decided (perhaps stupidly) to update my Ubuntu 18.04 VM to Ubuntu 20.04, and now I can't connect to it.

The machine starts up ok in Hyper-V, but the connection just hangs on the Hyper-V loading screen.

A little investigation in PowerShell showed me that the machine doesn't appear to have an IP address assigned to it, and trying to use the "Shut down" option through Hyper-V errors with the message

> 'VM' failed to stop. The device is not ready for use.

I'm kind of stuck as to what to try next, is there any hope for my VM, or have I managed to create a (virtual) paperweight (to keep all my emails from flying away).

Network adapter is set to "Default switch", as networking really isn't my forte, and until now, it seemed to work fine.

Comment: It's not a perfect answer by any means, but if you're in a hurry, you could install VirtualBox on the host machine, and clone your Hyper-V VM (.vhdx?) using CloneVDI (https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=22422 ; the download link is around mid-page) or VB's built-in command line "VBoxManage clonemedium". I've done it in the past with Windows servers, and if you give the new VM the same specs as in Hyper-V (same RAM, CPU, VRAM, etc...), it works OK. Not great, but OK. No hiccups, just not very fast, but stable. If you go command line, go admin. No guarantee it'll work with Ubuntu.

Comment: @Didier I did think of that, unfortunately I use Docker through Hyper-V, so do need Hyper-V running (and I'm 85% sure that you can't run both Hyper-V and VirtualBox at the same time)

Comment: Aaaah, good ole Docker... Such a marvelous idea on principle... You're right, you can't run the same VM using VB and Hyper-V, but you can run a VM and its clone side-by-side using both VM platforms. Then there's the Docker problem...

Comment: I'm not sure what causes the issue on Ubuntu's side, but do know when this occurs, it should still be possible to RDP into Ubuntu if you've configured RDP (something I'd recommended anyways, else you're locked to specific resolutions on Hyper-V)